# Why are Suriname, Belize, and Guinea-Bissau classified as "Small Island Developing States"?

Tags: united-nations, suriname, belize, guinea-bissau

From the [Wikipedia article on Small Island Developing States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Island_Developing_States), I was surprised to find Suriname, Belize, and Guinea-Bissau.  None of those are on islands.  Why are they included in this category?

(One might also question why Singapore is listed as a developing state, but that is a different question)

Comment: I presume it's related to politics inside the UN - Suriname could probably obtain some international grant by signing up for the SIDS scheme, so they did. A few hundred million in extra aid is well worth the ridicule.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the catch, quoting from a 2014 UN (and more precisely [UNDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Development_Programme)) [publication](https://www.undp.org/sites/g/files/zskgke326/files/publications/GPCSE_Complexity%20in%20Small%20Island.pdf), is that it seems it's simply a matter of self-identification

> Some 52 countries and ‘associate states’ **declare themselves**
> to be Small Island Developing States (SIDS), including 38 UN
> Member States listed on the website of the Office of the High
> Representative for the Least Developed Countries, Landlocked
> Developing Countries and Small Island Developing States. But
> there is no accepted definition—three SIDS are not even islands. [...]
>
> Not all SIDS are islands:
> Belize, Guyana and Suriname declare themselves to have the
> characteristics of SIDS, and therefore are SIDS, despite being
> continental countries.

So, it's probably better to rephrase this is why do they do that, which I don't have ready answers for, although they could possibly be invoking some of Hulk's arguments.

Although it's a 24-page paper, it basically never discusses Suriname, Belize, or Guyana in any detail. The only other time one of these is mentioned besides to say that they are not islands is to say:

> The loss of skilled people from small
> states is extremely high: the percentage of college graduates
> who migrate is as high as 86 percent in Guyana and 83 percent
> in Jamaica.

I think Guinea-Bissau had not yet declared itself a SIDS at that point (2014), since it's not included/mentioned at all in that paper.

There's a [36-page](https://www.unep.org/resources/report/small-island-developing-states-numbers) UN document (apparently from 2013 or 2014, but that's rather unclear) that mentions these a few more times, e.g.

> with the exception of two Caribbean countries — Suriname and Guyana — the
> EEZ of each small island developing state is larger than its terrestrial area

It also shows Suriname as having 68% of its population living at a height of less than 5 meters, which puts in among top between SIDS in this category. (The average for SIDS is something like 29%.)

Guinea-Bissau is only mentioned to say:

> In particular, Guinea-Bissau, Comoros and Haiti have the highest under-five mortality rates.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the name is just somewhat misleading.

There are 3 groups of especially vulnerable countries represented by the ["United Nations Office of the High Representative for the Least Developed Countries, Landlocked Developing Countries and Small Island Developing States"](https://www.un.org/ohrlls/content/about-us) - with some overlap between them.

The ["Small Island Developing States"](https://www.un.org/ohrlls/content/about-small-island-developing-states) are those for which the maritime resources are most important:

> For SIDS, the Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ)—the ocean under their control—is, on average, 28 times the country’s land mass. Thus, for many SIDS the majority of the natural resources they have access to comes from the ocean.

As opposed to the ["Landlocked Developing Countries"](https://www.un.org/ohrlls/content/landlocked-developing-countries), which face different challenges.

It seems that the key distinguishing factor is the relative importance of the effects of climate change on the oceans - i.e. these "island countries" are economically dependent on the sea, and also have large parts of the population living in areas that will be affected by rising sea levels.

---

For Suriname, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suriname#Economy) says:

> More than 93% of Suriname's landmass consists of unspoiled rain forest

> The vast majority of Suriname's inhabitants (about 90%) live in Paramaribo or on the coast.

There are also some raw materials, although their relative importance seems to have drastically changed in recent years:

> The economy of Suriname was dominated by the bauxite industry, which accounted for more than 15% of GDP and 70% of export earnings up to 2016. Other main export products include rice, bananas, and shrimp. Suriname has recently started exploiting some of its sizeable oil and gold reserves.

with gold being 78.4% of exports in 2019 according to the info-graphic, with bauxit no longer mentioned.

Comment: I still don't see how that applies to Suriname. Its main exports [appear to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Suriname) "Gold, alumina, Wood, crude oil, lumber, shrimp and fish, rice, bananas" — only two of those depend on the ocean.

Comment: "also have large parts of the population living in areas that will be affected by rising sea levels." Quantify that, please? How much land in Suriname do you expect to become uninhabitable as a result? How many people do you expect would be displaced by the next 1 metre of sea level rise, which at current rates will take [300 years per NASA data](https://sealevel.nasa.gov/faq/8/is-the-rate-of-sea-level-rise-increasing/)?

Comment: "affected" is not equivalent to "permanently flooded" or "uninhabitable". I expect more frequent and stronger floods, storms, etc, based on the models I've seen so far. But I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you've linked to a page whose primary purpose is to show that the increase in sea level is accelerating and then extrapolated based on the assumption that the rate of increase remains constant.  The page absolutely does not support the conclusion that it will take 300 years for sea levels to rise 100 cm.  If we instead assume that the rate of acceleration is constant at 0.03 mm/year/year, the next meter of sea level rise will take 169 years, and when a child born today turns 80 the increase will be 37 cm.

Comment: @phoog cool. Feel free to explain why the practical impact of sea level rise on that scale is so severe.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Hulk's answer, these countries' logistics and economics strongly resemble islands:

- Their road networks are poorly integrated with the rest of their continent.
- They have neither a populous hinterland, nor a wealthy city, so they do not have enough shipping demand to justify a major harbor.
- Many categories of goods (and energy) need to be imported at small scales, if they are to be available at all.  This makes these products expensive.

Comment: Some sources would be good.